# Active Storage: Update S3 on Model Update, Delete S3 on Model Delete

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using Active Storage on Rails 5.2.1

I have followed the tutorial and I am using the credentials to set it up in my `storage.yml`

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws_access_key_id! %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws_secret_key! %>
  region: us-east-1
  bucket: bucket-on-aws
```

company.rb:
`has_one_attached :image, dependent: :purge_later`

development.rb: `config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

I can upload and view the images. My issues are coming when I delete the company, it is not deleted from S3. The same goes when I update the image. Do I actually have to do all of that myself? I would have expected Active Storage to handle the deletion at the very least....especially with an option named `dependent: :purge_later`

I did try the actual purging from the console:
`c.image.purge` does indeed work. But I worry about never being able to purge images that were left behind after updating.

I generally do updates on the entire model:

companies_controller.rb: `@company.update(company_params)`

What is the `rails way` to handle these two situations?

Answer (score 0):

Went into the development logs and saw that `Sidekiq` hadn't been restarted since the changes....meaning it still thought that it was using local storage! Be sure to restart sidekiq or whatever you use for background jobs